# Is there a better/more concise way to write this query?

Tags: mysql

I am writing a query for a stock database and I am looking for the top 5 stocks in terms of price increase for each year (2010 - 2016). Right now I am writing it like this:

```
(
   SELECT Ticker, Year, MAX(High - Low)
   FROM Stocks
   WHERE Year = 2010
   GROUP BY Ticker
   ORDER BY MAX(High - Low) DESC
   LIMIT 5
)
UNION ALL
(
   SELECT Ticker, Year, MAX(High - Low)
   FROM Stocks
   WHERE Year = 2011
   GROUP BY Ticker
   ORDER BY MAX(High - Low) DESC
   LIMIT 5
)
UNION ALL
```

and repeating that for each year until 2016.

The create table statement is:

```
CREATE TABLE Stocks (
    Year   DATE
    Ticker VARCHAR(8),
    High   FLOAT,
    Low    FLOAT,
    Volume FLOAT,
    PRIMARY KEY(Ticker, Year)
);
```

And the resulting data set would be something like this:

```
Year    Ticker    MAX(High - Low)
---------------------------------
2010    GOOG      100
2010    FB        99
2010    AAPL      98
2010    NFLX      97
2010    ABCD      96
2011    FB        120
2011    ABCD      112
etc... (Top 5 in terms of high-low per year)
```

Is there a better and more concise way to write this?

Comment: Yes. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry I'm sorry, but I don't see how that link answers my question. Are you saying I should add the create table statements and a desired result set so that it would be easier to answer?

Comment: What other interpretation could there be?

Comment: @Strawberry Is this easier to understand now?

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked question is entirely self-explanatory (even if I say so myself).

Answer (score -1):

You can try IN statement.

```
SELECT Ticker, Year, MAX(High - Low)
FROM Stocks
WHERE Year IN ('2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016')
GROUP BY Ticker
ORDER BY MAX(High - Low) DESC
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that will combine everything together - you'll end up with the top 5 for the entire 2010-2016 period instead of the top 5 in each year.

Comment: Also need to group by Year as this would probably error with it not being a group by field (MYSQL can ignore this, but shouldn't)